# Why is android activity action bar title black?

Tags: android, android-activity, styles, android-api-levels

When I made projects using Android Studio before, the activity action bar title was white by default.
I created a new project with same settings as the previous projects (API level 11), but the default color of the activity title color is black. I didn't change anything at all, this is a fresh project.
I tried using styles but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action bar title color for a new project depends on the default theme used.In case of dark action bar the title color is white,please go and check the theme used in manifest.

Comment: It uses the default theme, which is this.
`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>`
\n
I'm sorry for the messy code. Don't know how to format it in this site.

Comment: try replacing  "Theme.AppCompat.Light"    by "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" when your action bar theme is dark the title automatically gets light  & for adding any code on here just give four spaces before the line it will get formatted

Answer (score 0):

in order to change the color of actionbar title you can you can use this code in your class :

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
// to choose white
```

or change your actionbar style in **`res/values/styles.xml`** file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

keep in mind you should change the style you chose before in manifest.xml for your app

Comment: Where is `MyTheme` found? Should it already be there? I'm getting errors on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it programmatically below is the code.

The ActionBar ID is not available directly, so you have to do little bit of hacking here.

```
 int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```